# What is the source and authenticity of this narrative on women visiting graves?

Tags: hadith, source-identification, authenticity

Abdullah Ibn Abi Mulaykah is also reported to have said, "Once 'Aishah returned after visiting the graveyard. I asked, 'O Mother of the Believers, where have you been?' She said: 'I went out to visit the grave of my brother Abd ar-Rahman.' I asked her: 'Didn't the Messenger of Allah, peace be upon him, prohibit visiting graves?' She said, 'Yes, he did forbid visiting graves during the early days, but later on he ordered us to visit them'." This is reported by Al-Hakim and Al- Baihaqi, who also remarked that this hadith was narrated only by Bistam bin Muslim al-Basri.

Comment: Well you've mentioned the sources and there are certainly other sources conforming it. See for example [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/30283/13438)

Comment: @Medi1Saif Do you have the Arabic text by any chance?

Comment: Your post already cites two sources [Hakim](https://al-maktaba.org/book/2266/1407#p1) and [Bayhaqi](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33024/8356#p1), and it is covered in Medi1Saif's linked answer that al-Iraqi and [al-Albani](https://al-maktaba.org/book/22592/1102#p1) graded it as authentic.

Comment: @UmH Oh, I'm very sorry. I didn't notice the links. Thank you very much for your help guys!